# Is it safe to call stringByReplacingCharactersInRange in UITextView's delegate textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:?

Tags: ios, ios4, nsstring, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I implemented a customized textview based on UITextView, trying to listen the text change event. So I implemented the UITextView's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    //It crashes!
    NSString *result = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    return YES;
}
```

In iOS 5 and iOS 6,the above code works fine. But in iOS 4.3, it crashes with the exception `***-[NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds`. 
I printed all the variable values, found in iOS 4.3, sometimes the range is out of bound indeed: `textView.text.length` is 111, but the `range` is `113,0`. What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: NSString *result = [[textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text]copy]; try this instead of  NSString *result = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

Comment: @Sudha Thanks! But it still crashes. And I think the crash came from the `Range or index out of bounds`.

Comment: get your textview.text in new string and pass that string in your result string........ I tried this and it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you calling `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText` manually from anywhere in your project?  This should work fine, unless it is manually called with incorrect paramaters.

Comment: @lnafziger Thanks for your reply! Yes, You are right, I did manually call the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText` in my code, and I forgot I had changed the range in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This method is automatically called whenever a change is made in a textview, and is very stable.  My guess (as you confirmed in your comment above) is that you must be calling this method manually in your code, and providing an incorrect range.